Aws ssm connection success but not working
I want to ask a question about AWS
I can access my ec-2 through ssm connect by using aws web service.
But when I enter aws ssm start-session --target [ec2-id] from the local terminal, there is no error and it does not work.
I have tried the following reasons myself, but they are all normal.

Is the ssm-agent of ec2 functioning normally? The answer is yes
Has SSMInstanceProfile been added to ec2: The answer is yes
Enter whether the iam user of aws cli has joined the policy: the answer is to join "AmazonSSMFullAccess"

I want to know what could be the cause, and how to fix it?
